# Encrypt the content using AES and mimekit

Tags: c#, aes, secret-key, smime, mimekit

I looked at several questions on stackoverflow and I'm not able to find answer pertaining to my requirement. So I'm posting this question:

**My requirement says:**
*The content must be encrypted using AES in FIPS Publication 197 (incorporated by reference in provision 6 of this Standard), and RFC 3565 (incorporated by reference in provision 6 of this Standard).
And it should be signed with RSA algorithm specified in RFC 4056.*

I saw this post: [MimeKit encrypt Message with AES](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43918221/mimekit-encrypt-message-with-aes)

```
    CmsRecipient CmsRecipient = new CmsRecipient("mail.cer");
    CmsRecipient.EncryptionAlgorithms = new EncryptionAlgorithm[] { EncryptionAlgorithm.AES256 };
    to1.Add(CmsRecipient);

    var signed = MultipartSigned.Create(ctx, signer, multipart);
    var encrypted = ApplicationPkcs7Mime.Encrypt(ctx, to1, signed);
    message.Body = MultipartSigned.Create(ctx, signer, encrypted);
```

It seems like in the above code, we expect the AES key to be part of the "mail.cer" certificate?
How do we encrypt the mail content using AES key and mimekit libraries, provided I've a secret key in the form of a string?

Comment: A public key is embedded in the certificate. Do you not have a certificate? You need both for S/MIME.

Comment: I've a sign certificate. But for encrypting the message content, I only have an AES secret key. I don't have a certificate. how do I handle that?

Comment: I honestly don't know :(

Comment: The certificate has a private key and the signed document has a public key.   Your string is the private key.  The public key is the signature in the signed document.  AES has different options (see Cipher and Algorithm Tables : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security)  The algorithm is described in RFC 3447 Para 8.1.1 (RSASSA-PSS): https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3447.

Comment: Keys are normally distributed in a certificate but  can be sent with just the key string.

Comment: If mail.cer is the public certificate of the recipient. When I specify EncryptionAlgorithm.Aes256, does mimekit libraries generate a temporary Aes key and encrypt with the public certificate of the recipient?

Comment: I'm just trying to understand how AES and RSA work together in mimekit. How do I generate a temporary AES key, encrypt the content of the message with AES key and then also encrypt the secret AES key with Public certificate of the sender and send that encrypted key as part of the mail message? Is there an example?

Comment: RSA would be used for the key encryption algorithm while AES would be the content encryption algorithm.